# c++ winsock (winsock2) recv() skips \0 byte

Tags: winsock, winsock2, recv

I'm sending the following data from server:

```
31 37 38 33 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 33 34 37 78 35
74 32 71 39 37 34 79 35 74 76 38 35 67 6e 32 6d
```

client side using **winsock2.h**:

```
...
int recvbuflen = 32;
char *tmpBuff = new char[recvbuflen];

int bytesRcvd = recv(conn_socket, tmpBuff, recvbuflen, 0);
...
```

So now:

```
bytesRcvd = 32;
tmpBuff = {31 37 38 33 33 34 37 78 35 74 32 71 39 37 34 79 35 74 76 38 35 67 6e 32 6d} in hex
```

basically **recv()** skips '\0' symbols during writing a receive buffer

How to receive all data with all '\0' symbols?

Comment: We need more code. In particular, the code that populates the buffer to send, the call to `send` and the code after `recv` that prints the output.

Comment: How is it possible? It says `bytesRcvd = 32` but received bytes stored in `tmpBuff` are less than 32? I don't think `recv()` actually makes any difference between zero and non-zero bytes.
I think you're doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`recv()` **DOES NOT** ignore any bytes, let alone `'\0'` bytes.  This is especially evident by the fact that `bytesRcvd` is being set to 32, which means all of the sent bytes are being received into the buffer correctly.  So something else is happening.  Most likely your debugger's inspection window for the buffer contents is the one actually ignoring the `'\0'` bytes.